# Use node modules with EJS and Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, datetimepicker

I need to import my datetimepicker js and style sheet into my EJS.

However, when I run it the CSS/JS do not render.

Here is my code layout.

EJS:

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/jquery- 
 datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css" >
<script src="node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery- 
datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const { kStringMaxLength } = require('buffer');

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Inside my view folder:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wondering in the future, I found the answer:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
```